# (Selenium, Python) Concatenate URL + CSV data, then open each URL in a new tab

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver

I wish to read a list of strings from a CSV file and concatenate the string with a URL, then open this complete URL list individually in each tab.
So far I am able to do either or.
I can read the data from the CSV file and open the data in each tab, or concatenate the URL + data and have it loop through the same tab.

I wish to use the CSV data string (7777777) and concatenate it to a URL "http://example.com/q="
Resulting in "http://example.com/q=7777777"
This data is then passed onto Selenium and each line in the CSV file is opened in its own tab

I can manually concatenate the URL using + but am not able to concatenate using + variable and have tried lot of ways but am probably making a syntax error somewhere.

This is what I have working so far and feel `.format(url + upc))` should work

A slightly edited version of the code will open all CSV data in individual tabs **if** the data is formatted as a URLS in the CSV, but the current CSV only consists of the UPC number and appending is required.

The expected result is for Selenium to open 3 **tabs** with the following URLs

```
https://www.example.com/q=7777777
https://www.example.com/q=8888888
https://www.example.com/q=9999999
```

test.csv

UPC
7777777
8888888
9999999

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    import pandas as pd

    PATH = "./chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

    upc = df['UPC']
    urls = "https://www.example.com/q="

    for url in urls:
    driver.execute_script('window.open("{}", "_blank",);'.format(url + upc))
    driver.close()
```

I am able to append the url using + 'str' but am not sure how to use a variable, and the ordering of the loop may be incorrect.
Thank you if you can advise

I have tried the following but get the error

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

```
urls = df['UPC']
link = "https://www.example.com/"


for url in urls:
    driver.execute_script('window.open("{}", "_blank",);'.format(link + url))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for url in urls:
        driver.execute_script('window.open("{}", "_blank",);'.format(link + str(url)))
driver.close()
```

got it as soon as i post the question, I need a duck it seems

Comment: if this is an answer to your question, make sure to select it as the correct answer

Comment: "... I need a duck it seems" haha